# PHP mongoDB cluster connection string is not working

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to connect to mongoDB cluster from PHP using below code

```
$client = new MongoClient('mongodb+srv://username:password@urlToCluster');
```

It gives me error as

```
Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'MongoClient::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known'
```

Not able to connect using connection string

Comment: The error means what it says, which is basically your machine where you are running the code cannot resolve the name you are giving it. Also `mongodb+srv` would not be used for `local` and not sure what this could possibly have to do with an SSH Tunnel. Chances are unless someone actually set up the DNS records for your server then you either A. Should not be using `mongodb+srv` and just mean `mongodb://` or B. You mean to connect to an Atlas hosted cluster, possibly not reachable by your application host because you never added it to the whitelist of allowed clients.

Comment: I am trying to connect to atlas cluster. It is already there. I am removing reference to SSH from question. It was separate DB

Comment: Then basically your application host cannot see the atlas cluster. As noted, you probably did not add your application host to the whitelist, OR your application host does not have access to touch the Atlas cluster from it's own network rules, or even do DNS lookups in general. **Not a programming problem**.

Comment: but using same credentials I can connect from terminal successfully.

Comment: does anybody have a working example? When I add this $client = new MongoDB\Client(....) to my code then the app shows a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MongoClient](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php) is deprecated long time ago and likely doesn't support new replica set syntax.

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/ recommends to use up to date [Mongodb driver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongodb.php):

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb+srv:////username:password@urlToCluster/?ssl=true&authSource=admin');
```